# how to fetch multiselect option values with dynamic id?

Tags: jquery, select, dropdown

I have few **multiselect dropdowns** in my page.So I need to get the values of that multiselect selected options with id.Here the id for the particular element will be generated dynamically.

I will loop through an array then

```
var value = $('#' + arrayObj[i]+'option:selected').val();
```

I am unable to the fetch the selected option value.Instead its showing undefined

Comment: are you trying to get element by id, but the `arrayObj[i]+` combines with `'option:selected'` which will become something like this: #arrayobjid**option:selected**..

Comment: Yes, I want to get the element value by id.Here the id will be dynamically generated not static. please share the needful solution

Comment: Why do you use the `option:selected` ? the `:selected` will do the work, see https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Comment: for suppose this code $('#language :selected').val(); is working for me.Here language is the select element id.
So,in my case the element id I need to pass dynamically through looping an array.In that case its showing undefined

Comment: try this 'var value = $('#' + arrayObj[i]).val();'

Comment: After removing option:selected it worked for me.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you could achive this. Hope it helps.

```js
const selectList = [
  {id: 'list1', options: ['a', 'b', 'c']}
];
selectList.map(select => {
  let list = '<select id="' + select.id + '" multiple></select>';
  $('#lists-container').append(list);
  select.options.map(option => {
    $('#' + select.id).append('<option>' + option + '</option>');
  });
  
  $('#' + select.id).on('change', evt => {
     let result = '';
     $(evt.target).children('option:selected' ).each(function() {
      result += $( this ).text();
    });
    $("#results").text(result);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="lists-container"></div>
<div id="results"></div>
```